# Extreme lag between controller input and seeing results on screen with the RetroN5?

Tags: retron-5

When trying to play a game on my RetroN5 (which is hooked up to an Insignia HDTV (that doesn't have "Game Mode") I have extreme latency between pushing a button on the controller and seeing the results on-screen.

Everything I have read suggests that the TV just isn't handling the video rendering and that I need to turn on "game mode".  However, the TV doesn't have game mode, and I have zero issue with responsiveness when playing Xbox-360, PS2, or using the TV as a monitor for a laptop.  It only occurs with the RetroN5.

This is acceptable for turn based games like Final Fantasy, Dragon Warrior, Romance of the Three Kingdoms, etc.  but when you try to play anything that requires even a shred of timing, the game is virtually unplayable.

Comment: Can you try it on another TV?  That way, you can eliminate whether it's the TV, or the console.

Comment: I wish I could but I only have the one HDTV and the RetroN5 only has an HDMI hookup.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably two things at play here:

#### 1. Your TV's Preprocessing (Game Mode)

As you've mentioned, newer (digital) TVs are prone to input lag, because the TV does a lot of preprocessing of the image before displaying it. This preprocessing isn't noticeable when you're watching TV and is only really needed for such DTV signals - not for connected PCs or Game Consoles like the RetroN 5.

A lot of the better designed TVs will have settings to remove or reduce the amount of preprocessing that the screen does, either overall or on a per-input level. Most more modern TVs call this 'Game Mode', and it is just a setting that you turn on or off, usually in 'General Settings'.

If you're unsure or can't find 'Game Mode', it may be called something else or instead is a series of settings you need to tweak/disable - try searching online for your particular brand/model.

#### 2. The Retron 5's Wireless controller

The default 'RetroN' controllers seem to suffer from what seems like ~10ms of input lag. It might not sound like much, but it is very noticeable especially on games where timing and perfect frames are everything.

This input lag **doesn't occur using original-console controllers** (Mega Drive, NES etc). My suggestion would be to get some OG controllers and relegate the wireless one to games where input lag does not matter too much (Pokemon etc)

Comment: I have only ever used the original controllers with my RetroN 5 and I still get horrible input lag, especially on SNES games (NES and GBA aren't as badly affected). This tells me that the problem is primarily with the SNES emulator in the RetroN.

Comment: @fluffy - what TV are you using?

Comment: An LG from a few years ago, kept in game mode. None of my other HDMI-based systems have this problem, and they are all routed through a switcher on the same input. It is definitely not a problem with the TV.